# how to handle a duplicate file while placing a same file existing folder in c#.net

Tags: vb.net

here i am reading files from one root folder and after reading that we are moving that particular file Success folder and taking a copy of that in to back up folder normal

while reading file i will check file naming convention by targeting backup folder  if suppose it was exists in backup folder then i m moving the file to duplicate folder

my problem if suppose again same file came to process this file already existed in duplicate folder how do send the file in to duplicate folder, unfornately i dint have any property as file rename any way can anybody give some suggestion to resolve from issue please.

```
 If File.Exists(Swift_Backup + "\" + Path.GetFileName(CBFile)) Then
                ' File.Move(CBFile, Swift_Duplicate + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(CBFile)) 'DUPLICATE FOLDER' 

                ' File.Copy(oldFileName, NewFileName);


                File.Copy(CBFile, Swift_Duplicate + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(CBFile) + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt") + Path.GetExtension(CBFile)) 'DUPLICATE FOLDER' 
                File.Delete(CBFile)
   END IF
```

i have tried like this but was not worked out for am i did any mistake

Swift_Duplicate --> duplicate folder name
Swift_Backup    --> backup folder name 
CBFile --> string filename will be there in cbfile, it will fetch from the root folder

Comment: Why did it not work? What was the error message (if any)? Whats the value of Swift_Duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

Renaming a file is the same as moving it to the same directory with a different name. For example:

```
File.Move("C:\\docs\\new.doc", "C:\\docs\\old.doc");
```

Also, consider using FileInfo class:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("C:\\docs\\new.doc");
file.MoveTo("C:\\docs\\new.doc");

FileInfo copy = file.CopyTo("C:\\docs\\old.doc");
```